# Why is there no insert() method for strings in Python?

Tags: python, string

Lists already have an insert() method that works with indexes:

```
>>> someList = [1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> someList
[1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> someList.insert(2, 3)
>>> someList
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If strings also have indexes, why not an insert() method for them too? Example below:

```
>>> someString = 'foobar'
>>> someString.insert(3, 'SPAM')
>>> someString
'fooSPAMbar'
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, duh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer: Because strings are immutable.

Every type in Python is either mutable (like a list, a dictionary, or a normal object) , or immutable (like tuples, strings, ints, ...).

That's why you can append, pop, and insert in and from lists, but not tuples.
When you do something like this:

```
a = "this"
a = a + "that"
```

`a` seems to have "changed" to `"thisthat"`, but actually, the name `a` just points to a new string. You can observe that effect if you hand something to a function and try to modify it in the function: Mutable types will also change outside (although you should usually avoid these side-effects), while immutables won't:

```
a = 3
b = [3]
def change_a(something):
    something = 4
def change_b(something):
    something[0] = 4
change_a(a)
change_b(b)
print(a,b) # prints "3 4"
```

If you need to mutate strings, you might want to look into [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) for Python 2, or [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) for Python 3, respectively:

```
import io
def insert(s,where,what):
    whatlen=len(what)
    s.seek(0)
    cur=len(s.read())
    if cur < where:
        raise IndexError("Can't insert at position {}: Index out of bounds"
                .format(where))
    s.seek(where)
    r=s.read()
    s.seek(where+whatlen)
    s.write(r)
    s.seek(where)
    s.write(what)

s = io.StringIO("This is a test")

insert(s,5,"hello")
s.seek(0)
print(s.read()) #prints "This hellois a test"
```

Comment: `MutableString` may be worth mentioning.

Comment: `MutableString` is deprecated in Python 2 and non-existent in Python 3.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if he's looking for a workaround that's a good option.

Comment: I added a reference to StringIO for something like mutable strings. Since they didn't specify the version of Python they're using, I'm assuming the most recent one.

Comment: `StringIO` doesn't seem to have any methods as described in the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Because strings are immutable.  You can't change the contents of a string.  You'd have to make a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Because strings are decidedly immutable. As are tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional strings are immutable. You can actually use the deprecated `MutableString` to do this:

```
string = UserString.MutableString('foobar') # then insert, call string.insert(3, 'SPAM')
```

Comment: I believe `MutableString` is actually internalized with a list.

Answer (score 0):

Hence List are a mutable we can make changes in a list. But Strings ar ean immutable one, we can append charaters in a string. But we cannot change the index position values in a string.